# mongoDB use updateMany with array

Tags: mongodb

I have an array like this

```
timelogs [
{
_id: 611229a40f42a10e5dcfa545,
dtstart: 2021-07-28T07:15:03.722Z,
idstory: 611229040f42a10e5dcf04e3,
idworkday: 611229a30f42a10e5dcfa4c6,
idclient: 611228fa0f42a10e5dcefee6,
idowner: 611228fb0f42a10e5dcefef9,
dtend: 2021-08-10T13:29:12.640Z,
comment: 'test1'
},
{
_id: 61127f2bf1e36e5fe2e463c3,
dtstart: 2021-08-10T13:29:15.158Z,
idstory: 611229040f42a10e5dcf04e3,
idworkday: 611229a30f42a10e5dcfa4c6,
idowner: 611228fb0f42a10e5dcefef9,
idclient: 611228fa0f42a10e5dcefee6,
comment: 'test2'
}
]
```

I also get their IDs to filter by them.

```
[611229a40f42a10e5dcfa545,61127f2bf1e36e5fe2e463c3]
```

Is it possible to dynamically substitute values from an array into $set, so that it would be something like this?

```
const filter = {
   _id: {
      $in: timelogsIds, // [611229a40f42a10e5dcfa545,61127f2bf1e36e5fe2e463c3]
   },
 };

 db
 .collection('timelogs')
 .updateMany(filter, {
   $set: {
       // add dynamically values from the array
       // for example,  timelogs.$[].comment 
   },
  });
```

Comment: your question is not clear what do you need to substitute? *Is it possible to dynamically substitute values from an array into $set*?

Comment: @turivishal i need to update 2 fields: dtend, comment. The question is, is it possible, without a loop, through updateMany, to somehow update these values, if I have an array where the elements have different _id

Comment: you want to update same value in both array of object properties? please post your requirement with details.